# How do I create a fixed header(not sticky header), but the content goes behind the header in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I referred the following article for sticky header
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sticky_header

But I don't want

```
<div class="top-container">
  <h1>Scroll Down</h1>
  <p>Scroll down to see the sticky effect.</p>
</div>
```

in my html.

All I need is , the "My Header" to be always on top, but when user scrolls the content, the excess old content on top should go behind the "My Header".

I added `position:fixed` under `myHeader` div, but I don't think that's the proper way to fix. 
It did work if I do it, but for a similar web page it doesn't work. 
I guess adding position works for this case, because this is a sample within a web page.

Please help.

Comment: share your code

Comment: for this you should use `position: fixed;` like you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you want can be achieved with a small tweak in the javascript code from the reference you have used. Replace the javascript code in your html page with following and it would work the way you want it to.

```
<script>
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= 1) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: This works. Could you explain what its doing vs. the referenced article.. I couldn't get it.

Comment: In your code when you set window.pageYOffset >= sticky, it says when the element with id 'myHeader' reaches top of the window, make it sticky, so the header in your code sticks only after a little scroll. 

but in the code i mentioned, it says the element with id 'myHeader' should stick to the top immediately when the page vertically scrolls more than 1px (ie window.pageYOffset >= 1). This way it sticks to top immediately after user starts scrolling. I hope you understood.

Comment: Completely understood. Very well explained. Thanks a ton. I have one last question
Does keyword window, document belong to DOM or WebAPI or HTML or JQuery?

Comment: These keywords belong to javascript/jquery.